# Can't open vlc on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04, vlc

I've just installed VLC on my Ubuntu PC, but when I try to run the application it just doesn't start. I've tried a lot of things like re-installing it, but nothing seems to work. If I try to start it with Terminal (I only know the basics) it gives a "segmentation fault (core dumped)".

I also discoverd that when I install VLC with "apt-get" I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Regenerating VLC plugin cache failed.
Please run 'vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins' manually.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you do what it says which error do you get?

Comment: if you run **vlc -I skins2** got a crash?

Comment: @dadexix86 it sais that vlc-cashe-gen isn't a vallid command.

Comment: @LilloX it gives a segmentations fault (core dumped).

Comment: Sorry man, got a segmentation fault before it did something... (@starkus)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins` in terminal?

Maybe `sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc` will help.
As well as`sudo dpkg --configure -a`.
You can also try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure vlc` as well as
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -f`.

To reset VLC just use `vlc --reset-config`.

Answer (score 0):

on a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04 using the command `sudo apt-get install vlc` was able to open the application and use it as normal.

If installing using `apt-get` is not working then try the built in Ubuntu software center and see if installing it from there will work.

Comment: `apt-get` and the Software Center are both just front-ends for `apt`. If one fails to install, the other very likely won't be successful either.

Comment: try this... no luck

Answer (score 0):

had allready tried `vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins`, no luck, "vlc-cache-gen" isn't a vallid command on my Terminal...

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -f` didn't solve the problem, I got the same warning...

`"vlc --reset-config"` gave another reaction:
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I think it could have something to do with that segmentation fault, but I've Googled that allready and couldn't find an answer there. Maybe you'll have move luck...

Update:
VLC-Nox 3.0.0 crashes when I try to open it... Someone knows how to fix that?